# MySQL DATE_ADD converts date to 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Any pointer would be appreciated! I can't spot what's wrong with the syntax, didn't find an answer on SO, so I'm posting my question here. Thanks in advance!

Here's what I tried:

```
mysql> select DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 week), DATE_ADD(end_date, 
INTERVAL 2 week) from lists where id=1;
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------
-------+
| DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 week) | DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 
week) |
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------
-------+
| 2017-05-28                            | 2017-06-11                          
|
+---------------------------------------+------------------------------
-------+
```

Result looks correct. Then I tried:

```
mysql> update lists set start_date=DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) and 
end_date=DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 WEEK) where id=1;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0' for column 'start_date' at row 
1
```

Did some research on SO, some answers point to strict mode. But in order to trigger strict mode error, the computed dates need to be 0 first, and I can't see how the above syntax could cause DATE_ADD to do that.

Just for the sake of testing, then I tried this:

```
mysql> update ignore lists set start_date=DATE_ADD(start_date, 
INTERVAL 2 week) and end_date=DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 week) where 
id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
```

It gave this result:

```
mysql> select start_date, end_date from lists where id=1;
+------------+------------+
| start_date | end_date   |
+------------+------------+
| 0000-00-00 | 2017-05-28 |
+------------+------------+
```

How???

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Upvoting this question from new SO user. Why? because it's well asked. Not every good question has to have a hard answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops. You have `and` where you should have a comma.

```
 update lists 
    set start_date=DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 2 WEEK),
        end_date=DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
  where id=1;
```

`and` is a boolean operator returning either `0` or `1`. So MySQL's parser doesn't choke on it, but rather tries to evaluate it. Hence your zero.

I hate when that happens.

Comment: thank you for catching that! i overlooked that "and" :)